# Cluster and Non cluster index in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 version to create database.

I have the following table test with some columns list.

```
create table test
(
  cola varchar(10),
  colb varchar(10),
  colc varchar(10),
  cold varchar(10)
);
```

Now I want to create a indexs on some columns.

For example:

I want to create clustered index for columns `cola` and `colb`.

And I want to create non clustered index for columns `colc` and `cold`.

As I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796548/about-clustered-index-in-postgres) And [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-types.html) ,I come to know that there is no clustered and non clustered index in PostgreSQL.

**My Question**: What type of index I can use instead of clustered and non clustered index in PostgreSQL,Which does the same job as clustered and non clustered indexes does?

Comment: Every index in Postgres is "non-clustered". Postgres does not have clustered indexes.If you run `create index` it will create a (non-clustered) B-Tree index. Why do you think there is no non-clustered index?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Okay! My bad. But how can I create clustered index?

Comment: As I said: Postgres doesn't have clustered indexes. So you can't create one. Why do you think you need one?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, So `create index` does both job in PostgreSQL.

Comment: It **only** creates non-clustered indexes because Postgres does not have a clustered indexes

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> My Question: What type of index I can use instead of clustered and non clustered index in PostgreSQL,Which does the same job as clustered and non clustered indexes does?

PostgreSQL doesn't have the concept of clustered indexes at all. Instead, all tables are heap tables and all indexes are non-clustered indexes.

Just create a non-clustered index when you'd usually create a clustered index.

More details:

- http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index 
  You might want to read the [whole chapter](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering) to get proper understanding of these concepts.

Comment: @mak: I also find this blog from Markus very interesting: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,  Yeah! It is.

Comment: It appears the Postgres implements something that at least approximates a *clustered index*:


"CLUSTER instructs PostgreSQL to cluster the table specified by
table_name based on the index specified by index_name"


From the postgres docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html

Comment: @mangotang See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47669397/157957). In short, `CLUSTER` reorganises the *current* data in a table based on a particular index, but does not create a different data structure or maintain that order.

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you for the clarification. By saying that postgres "_approximates_ a clustered index", I was attempting to be clear that it is in fact _not_ a clustered index, but _may_ be a viable alternative.

Comment: You are saying PG don't have clustered index, but I see they do https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html .. What am I missing?

Comment: @ArupRakshit You are missing the fact that PostgreSQL uses the term cluster for a different concept. PostgreSQL clustering is ordering the rows in a table according to the order defined by an index. Whereas a "clustered index" in some databases refers to the concept of having all columns stored in the index. Similar names, different concepts.

Comment: @MarkusWinand Indeed, `CLUSTER` does not implement a clustered index because it does not maintain the ordering nor stores the data in the index, however I propose it should be mentioned in your answer since it does have some of the performance gain of clustered indices - as it will dramatically decrease page reads when an index is found. It would benefit both the OP as well as people searching for similar information.

Answer (score 1):

For a clustered index, each of the desired fields must be the **primary key**. And for the non-clustered index, we act according to the following command :

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Test_Colc ON test(colc);

CREATE INDEX IX_Test_Cold ON test(cold);
```