# Best practice for Cluster Index on Postgres for multi-tenant architecture

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant

If I have a multi-tenant architecture using a Postgres DB is it beneficial to create the AccountId as part of the Cluster Index? Any references to some good database design principles for large multi-tenant architecture designs?

As example:

CREATE TABLE orders (
orderid uuid NOT NULL,
accountid bigint NOT NULL,
.
.
)

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have a "Cluster index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jjanes corrected me that Postgres does not have a Cluster Index by design. You can use the CLUSTER command to re-order records by an index. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html

This post explains it well.
[About clustered index in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796548/about-clustered-index-in-postgres)

Using CLUSTER should reduce the seek time where the Account is part of the index.
https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/10-How-does-CLUSTER-ON-improve-index-performance.html